# Use INTO fields as parameters in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Id like to know how can i get a INTO field and use as parameter in a cursor to display lines that meet a condition?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CONTR_VAC_KID AS
VACINE DOSE.VAC_ID%TYPE;
VACINES_KIDS DOSE%ROWTYPE;
CURSOR DOSES(VAC) IS
SELECT * FROM DOSE WHERE VAC_ID=VAC;
BEGIN

SELECT D.Vac_Id INTO VACINE from kid_Vacine_Campaign CV INNER JOIN DOSE D ON CV.DOSE_ID = D.DOSE_ID WHERE Cv.kid_Id = 3 AND ROWNUM=1;
OPEN DOSES(VACINE);
LOOP
FETCH DOSES INTO VACINES_KIDS;
EXIT WHEN DOSES%NOTFOUND;
 dbms_output.put_line(VACINES_KIDS.DOSE_ID);
END LOOP;
CLOSE DOSES;
END;
/
```

Im getting this error

```
Error(8,61): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INNER" when expecting one of the following:     , ; for group having intersect minus order start union where    connect
```

Comment: prolly yes. Unfortunately the teacher doesnt want the updated ones

Comment: As far as I remember ANSI join syntax was introduced in Oracle 9i - 20 years ago!

Comment: By the way, it's *vaccine*.

Comment: Also, check out the handy [Cursor FOR loop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/cursor-FOR-LOOP-statement.html) syntax. It simplifies this kind of operation a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code gets two errors, and you seem to have ignored the first one:

```
Error(4, 17): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

   in out <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
   table ... columns long double ref char time timestamp
   interval date binary national character nchar
The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for ")" to continue.

Error(8, 57): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INNER" when expecting one of the following:

   , ; for group having intersect minus order start union where
   connect
```

The line:

```
CURSOR DOSES(VAC) IS
```

needs to declare the argument type, e.g.:

```
CURSOR DOSES(VAC DOSE.VAC_ID%TYPE) IS
```

That removes the second `INNER` error too; I believe that after encountering the first problem it is then confused and is maybe interpreting the `CV` table alias [as a function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CV.html#GUID-32E56E9C-4F59-486E-8E4C-F332284C5EA7). Anyway, it's a bogus error, so fix the first one reported and see how that changes things.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=79d3b2e445bc08cf629b564f9bc231fc)

Comment: nom im getting the error Error(7,83): PL/SQL: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: [Seems OK to me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5ace1f7226ed269f0c6ecbaf743c61ad). Not sure what you're doing differently.